# cleaning up safely wordpress wp_postmeta table

Tags: post-meta, sql, optimization, customization

In a effort to facilitate maintenance of my site, optimise page loading , and also helping out db migration , i am trying to cleanup the wordpress database of my site.
i ahve realised the wp-postmeta table itself weights 240 Mo !!
How could i clean this out, distinguish what is required to what is not and safely remove useless content?

Comment: How would we know? :) It is your site and your data, the size alone is not indicator of garbage (there are _very_ large WP sites/databases out there).

Comment: true . it doesn't mean there is no general queries or tool for that matter. U don't know doesn't mean forcely the rest of the world don't have any answer to it , right?

Comment: Sorry. The question itself is impossible. There are 26,794 plugins at the time of writing. Any one of those could have written data to your post meta table, not to mention what themes or custom code may have done. And that is assuming that nothing does anything weird (and a lot of plugins/themes do things wrong). I am confident in saying that there is no general solution to cleaning your data. Asking for a tool recommendation is off-topic, by the way.

Answer (score 5):

The only generic semi-automatic procedure I can think of would be to delete post meta where the `post_id` is invalid.

```
SELECT * 
FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} as pm 
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} as p
  ON pm.post_id = p.ID
WHERE p.ID IS NULL
```

I wrote a `SELECT` and not a `DELETE` because I don't trust that to work in all cases. I have seen "dummy" or "placeholder" values in the postmeta table with a `post_id` of `0` or some absurdly high value. I am not saying those are good ideas, but I have seen that, so be aware. You are better off looking over the data returned by that `SELECT` and then deleting items selectively.

I don't really expect to get very far a *post meta* makes very little sense without *post*, except for a few questionably wise uses.

The other, very labor intensive thing you can do is look at the `meta_keys` in the database and try to spot keys belonging to plugins that you no longer use. It may or may not be possible to identify them, but you can try. Some plugins use identifiable prefixes or suffixes.

Comment: thanx very much for that . This query returned no entries but help me in understand the wp environment better